# I want to find the sum of range between two numbers?

Tags: c++, loops, function-definition

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std; 

void sumrange(int x, int y) {
int sum;
    cout << "Enter the first number: ";
cin >> x;
  cout << "Enter the second number: ";
cin >> y ;



int bnum = max(x,y);
int snum = min(x,y);

int i = snum;
while (i < bnum) { sum =+ i; i++; }

cout << sum;
}

int main() {

int x, y;
sumrange(x,y);

return 0;

}
```

I can't get the right answer from my input I tried 1 and 4 and the answer was 3 but it supposes to be 1+2+3+4 which is 10.

Comment: The variable sum is not initialized.

Comment: Off-topic: About [`using namespace std`]... And a `for` loop would have been more appropriate here: `for(int i = snum; i <= bnum; ++i) { sum += i; }`. Note: as you want to include `bnum` itself as well in the sum you need to compare for `<=`! A bit strange, too, is that you provide parameters to the function of which the values you never ever use anyway – just have local variables instead then. Within main passing uninitialised `x` and `y` to the function is undefined behaviour by the way – even though they are never read within `sumrange`.

Comment: Note that this can be implemented without a loop using the fact that `1+2+ ..+ n = n * (n+1)/2`, so assuming `x < y` , `x + (x+1) + ... +y = x + x * (y - x) + 1 + 2 + ... + (y - x) = x (y-x+1) + (y - x) * (y-x + 1) / 2`

Comment: Another variant of the closed formula: `(bnum * (bnum + 1) - (snum - 1) * snum) / 2`...

Comment: You are not checking the streams after input – always do so to catch invalid user input: `if(cin >> x) { /* OK, can go on */ } else { /* some appropriate error handling */ }`. While in given case it would result in one or both values being 0 you might end up in fatal errors another time...

Answer (score 2):

Couple of observations:

- don't use `using namespace std;` it is a bad practice and might lead to name conflicts
- variable `int sum` needs to be explicitly initialized before use
- `sum =+ i` should be `sum += i`
- you need to use `<=` if you want to include the upper bound
- take a look at the [arithmetic sequence](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-arithmetic.html)
- `sumrange` function doesn't need parameters, sice they are passed by value `int x, y;` from your `main` are not used at all

Following code should do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void sumrange()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int sum = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    std::cin >> y ;

    int bnum = std::max(x,y);
    int snum = std::min(x,y);

    int i = snum;
    while (i <= bnum) { sum += i; i++; }

    std::cout << sum;
}

int main() {
    sumrange();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have inverted the += sign to =+
It should be `sum += i` .
`sum = +i`  assigns the number to itself

Edit: you should also initialize sum, stated in the comment

Answer (score 1):

There are **3 problems** with your given code snippet.

**Problem 1:** `=+` should be `+=` in the statement:

```
sum =+ i;   //=+ should be +=
```

**Problem 2:** The variable `sum` is **uninitialized** and so it has a **garbage value**. Using that garbage value leads to **undefined behavior**.

**Problem 3:** Should use `<=` instead of `<` in the statement

```
while (i < bnum)  //should be i<=bnum
```

So the modified(corrected) program looks like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void sumrange(int x, int y) {
    int sum=0;///INITIALIZE sum
    std::cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    
    std::cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    std::cin >> y ;



    int bnum = std::max(x,y);
    int snum = std::min(x,y);

    int i = snum;
    while (i <= bnum) //USED <=
    { 
        sum += i; //USED +=
        i++;
     }

    std::cout << sum;
}

int main() {

int x, y;
sumrange(x,y);

return 0;

}
```

##### Alternative solution

Note that you can find the sum **without using a loop** as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void sumrange(int x, int y) {
    int sum=0;//initialize sum
    std::cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    
    std::cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    std::cin >> y ;

    sum = (std::abs(x - y) + 1) * (x + y) / 2; //ADDED THIS 

    std::cout << sum;
}

int main() {

int x, y;
sumrange(x,y);

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A C++20 solution :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    int a{ 0 };
    int b{ 0 };
    std::cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    std::cin >> b;


    auto lower_bound = std::min(a, b);
    auto upper_bound = std::max(a, b) + 1;  // iota view is exclusive so add 1

    auto view = std::ranges::iota_view{ lower_bound , upper_bound };
    auto sum = std::accumulate(view.begin(), view.end(), 0);

    std::cout << "sum = " << sum << "\n";

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Values of the function arguments are not used in this call

```
int x, y;
sumrange(x,y);
```

So such a call does not make a sense.

You need in main to ask the user to enter a range of numbers and pass the range to the function.

The task of the function is to return the calculated sum for the specified range in main.

Within the function `sumrange` the variable `sum` is not initialized.

```
int sum;
```

You need to initialize it to 0.

In this while loop

```
while (i < bnum) { sum =+ i; i++; }
                       ^^
```

there is a typo. Instead of the compound assignment operator `+=` you are using the assignment operator `=` and the unary `+` operator

Moreover as it follows from your comment you need also to add the value of `bnum` to the `sum`.

So the loop should look at least like

```
while (i <= bnum) { sum += i; i++; }
```

Pay attention to that in general an overflow can occur. So it is better to declare the variable `sum` as having the type `long long int`.

The function and the program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

long long int range_sum( int x, int y )
{
    long long int sum = 0;

    auto [first, last] = std::minmax( { x, y } );

    do
    {
        sum += first;
    } while (first++ != last);

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    std::cin >> x;

    std::cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    std::cin >> y;

    std::tie( x, y ) = std::minmax( { x, y } );

    std::cout << "The sum of numbers in the range ["
              << x << ", " << y << "] is equal to "
              << range_sum( x, y )
              << '\n';
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter the first number: 1
Enter the second number: 10
The sum of numbers in the range [1, 10] is equal to 55
```

Answer (score 1):

```
constexpr auto sumrange(const int x, const int y) noexcept {

    auto sum = 0;

    if (x < y) for (auto i = x; i <= y; ++i) sum += i; else 
    if (y < x) for (auto i = y; i <= x; ++i) sum += i;

    return sum;

}

int main() {

    constexpr auto x = 1;
    constexpr auto y = 3;

    constexpr auto r = sumrange(x, y); // 1 + 2 + 3

    std::cout << r << '\n'; // 6

}
```